# Unable to import project to SOnarQube after spliting repository

Tags: sonarqube

We extract a maven project from the main build to move it to its own repository.

---

Before we have only one git repository with:

```
Main  
|ProjectA  
|ProjectB  
|ProjectC
```

---

Now we have 2 repositories :

- the old one with only `Main`, `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`
- The new one with `projectC`

When I try to analyse the `ProjectC` I have an error from Sonar:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar
(default-cli) on project ProjectC is already part of project Main.
```

That is true : `ProjectC` is already a subcomponent of `Main`...

How can I import `ProjectC` ?
Or may be how can I remove the `projectC` of the components of `Main` ?

I don't want to keep old statistics of `projectC` inside `Main` as I will recreate the history in `ProjectC` with a script like this : https://gist.github.com/aslakknutsen/2422117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete a subcomponent from a project, you can only delete projects.

Unfortunately, it looks like you'll need to delete Main and then recreate both it and ProjectC